# Grub won't recognise USB stick

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub, operating-systems, cp

I am trying to boot to a USB stick using [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromUSB#Booting_via_GRUB). But unfortunately Grub won't recognise my usb stick when I type `root ([tab], 0)`. Is there any way to solve this issue? I've tried copying the files from the original ISO to the system but I get a `Input / output error`.

Comment: What do you mean with "I've tried copying the files from the original ISO"? What ISO? What system...

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob I mounted the Linux mint xfce ISO to the system then copied them. My current system is Wary puppy Linux.